# Rotating while "Vote to Close" dialog is open and choosing the option crashes the Android app

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app

App version: 1.0.52

When I have the "Vote to Close" dialog open and rotate the screen from horizontal to landscape, and back to horizontal, and then click on the "*Unclear what you are asking*" option, the app crashes.

Logcat:

```
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 1734
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.FlagDialog$1.onItemClick(FlagDialog.java:154)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
12-26 01:04:55.115 E/AndroidRuntime(1734): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. I guess since the rotation "destroys" and "recreates" the activity, a reference (probably the question ID, or the close reason ID) got lost (`null`) and crashes the app.